# How do you access the event that is used for dojo.event.connect in the function that is being called?

Tags: dojo, dom-events

First off, I am using a version of older version of dojo, so `dojo.event.connect` is the proper syntax.  My question is this: How do I access the event in the function that I call when the event is fired.

Basically, Ii am dynamically creating a button and then connecting an event on "onClick"

```
var _btn = dojo.widget.createWidget(widget parameters);
dojo.event.connect(_btn,"onClick","myFunction");
```

In `myFunction`, I need to be able to access the attributes of `_btn`.  I have tried passing `_btn` as the context of `dojo.event.connect` but this doesn't work.  It also wont pass `_btn` as a parameter for `myFunction` when I try that. Is it possible to either A) somehow pass `_btn` as a parameter into `myFunction` or B) Access the event that is fired in `myFunction` when `_btn` is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a more convenient way to solve your problem, but in the worst case, you could just use a closure as a surefire way to pass the parameter:

change myfunction from

```
myfunction(arg1, arg2){
```

into

```
myfunction(btn, arg1, arg2){
     //using btn here
```

and use dojo.partial (or dojo.hitch) to create a function that always reveives a certain button as a parameter (and then pass it to the connect):

```
dojo.event.connect(_btn, 'onClick', dojo.partial(myFunction, _btn));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just ended up doing a work-around that didn't require a dojo.connect and just manipulated the button's actual onClick method.  Thanks anyway!